# Method validate does not exist - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have a very weird problem. When I'm submitting the form, it throws an error with server-side validation.

Here is my simple controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Newsletter;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SubscriptionController extends Controller
{
    public function subscribe(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            ]);
    }
}
```

Submitting the form gives me:

> BadMethodCallException
>   Method validate does not exist.

it should work according to:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation

Comment: The linked page does not have any mention of a `$request->validate` . it has multiple mentions of `$this->validate($request,...)` though

Comment: @apokryfos yes, I also found that later on, my bad.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In docs said:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'required|email',
]);
```

This string - works :)

Comment: Works for Lumen too.

Comment: Works inside a Controller too.

Answer (score 9):

You should try this:

```
$validateFields = array('email' => 'required|email');

$this->validate($request, $validateFields);
```

**OR**

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'required|email'
]);
```

Answer (score 6):

Well means its no longer available in 5.4 however its available in controller

Try:

```
 $this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'required|email',
 ]);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
        $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'mobile_number' => 'required']);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
        }
```

**Hope this works for you..**

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Validator service provider.

```
     namespace App\Http\Controllers;

     use Newsletter;
     use Illuminate\Http\Request;
     use Validator;

     class SubscriptionController extends Controller
     {
          public function subscribe(Request $request)
          {
                   $request->validate($request->all(),[
                     'email' => 'required|email',
                  ]);
           }
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually If you add the right controller, validate method should be already included. You can try adding below controller.

Instead:
`use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;`

Answer (score 2):

Add validator service and clear cache after making changes

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;

class RecaptchaController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'phone' => 'required|min:10',
            'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha'
        ]);

        return "success";
    }
}
```

You can clear cache with the below artisan command on your terminal.
Note: remember to check the directory you run the command.

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use regex pattern of this email validation.

protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $messages = array('email.regex' => 'Your email id is not valid.');
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|regex:/(.*)@myemail\.com/i|unique:users',
     ],$messages);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

let's add these two packages
Best of luck

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

Comment: Please refrain your will to post an untested answer.