# BadMethodCallException explication?

Tags: laravel

When, I want to create a recording I have this error message?

[image]

> BadMethodCallException in  => C:\wamp64\www\exemple\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable.php line 74:
>   Method validate does not exist.

I don't understand the problem?

Controller - Student

```
public function index()
    {
        $students = Student::oldest()->paginate(5);
        return view('admin.students.index', compact('students'))
          ->with('i', (request()->input('page',1) -1)*5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.students.create', compact('students'));
    }


    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
                'name' => 'required',
                'firstname' => 'required'

        ]);


       $exists = Student::where('name', $request->get('name'))->where('firstname', $request->get('firstname'))->count();

       if (!$exists){
            Student::create($request->all());
            return redirect()->route('students.index')
                ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');
        }

        else{
            return redirect()->route('students.index')
                ->with('error', 'doublon');

        }   

    }
```

Comment: Can you share your code where you tried to validate your data?

Comment: Error not coming from blade templating engine, it's coming from a controller or custom class.

Comment: @Saularis: I have edited my first message. It's the create.blade.php the problem?

Comment: @user11124425, no, again error coming from the controller or your custom class where you put validate function.

Comment: @Rwd: Yes, sorry... I have edited my first message...

Comment: @Saularis: Perhaps my Controller? I have edited my first message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method validate does not exist - Laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45795508/method-validate-does-not-exist-laravel-5-4)

Comment: @Rwd: Yes, thank you ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code. Replace request by this

```
$this->validate([
      'name' => 'required',
      'firstname' => 'required'
]);
```